# Jenkins API not returning the console text but successful from the Browser

Tags: java, curl, jenkins, automation, continuous-integration

The console log is not returning any result via the Jenkins API:

```
curl -I http://$USER:$APITOKEN@$HOST:8080/job/Test1/121/consoleText -H "$CRUMB"
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
  0   657    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Fri, 05 Jan 2018 08:38:35 GMT
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
Content-Type: text/plain;charset=utf-8
Content-Length: 657
Server: Jetty(9.4.z-SNAPSHOT)
```

But, the Console log via the Chrome browser has all the build details:

The console is:

`http://localhost:8080/job/Test1/121/api/json?pretty=true`

The Response comes back as below:

```
 {
  "_class" : "hudson.model.FreeStyleBuild",
  "actions" : [
    {
      "_class" : "hudson.model.CauseAction",
      "causes" : [
        {
          "_class" : "hudson.model.Cause$RemoteCause",
          "shortDescription" : "Started by remote host 0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1",
          "addr" : "0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1",
          "note" : null
        }
      ]
    },
    {

    },
    {

    }
  ],
  "artifacts" : [

  ],
  "building" : false,
  "description" : null,
  "displayName" : "#120",
  "duration" : 1092,
  "estimatedDuration" : 1070,
  "executor" : null,
  "fullDisplayName" : "Test1 #120",
  "id" : "120",
  "keepLog" : false,
  "number" : 120,
  "queueId" : 120,
  "result" : "SUCCESS",
  "timestamp" : 1515135051624,
  "url" : "http://localhost:8080/job/Test1/120/",
  "builtOn" : "",
  "changeSet" : {
    "_class" : "hudson.scm.EmptyChangeLogSet",
    "items" : [

    ],
    "kind" : null
  },
  "culprits" : [

  ]
}
```

Has anyone faced this issue? There is a team that wants to monitor the build status and I felt this would be ideal for sharing all the details.

Answer (score 0):

I could not find a REST API that exposes the consoleText. So, I referred to the jenkins API documentation and sftp-ed the generated logs to a Splunk log-monitor.
Generic path is: `$JENKINS_HOME/jobs/$JOB_NAME/$BUILD_NUMBER/log` Now, I use the Splunk dashboard to look at the build log status. And splunk has a better rest-api support incase there are corrective steps we need to take.

Comment: You could also have used `{BUILD_URL}` which gets you everything up to the last slash.